# Redirect to store on first visit with observer/event

Tags: magento2, multistore

On the first visit i have to redirect the user to relative store view depending on the user's country (retrieved by IP).

I want to create a custom module for this purpose, so i think to need a magento event dispatched "before all" so i could set the right store view programmatically.

Is there an event that can afford to do this?

Comment: here some hints to my question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100019/magento2-re-direct-to-custom-url-from-observer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the first event dispatched `controller_action_predispatch`.

In the observer you could retrieve user's country with geo localization then redirect the user to the relative store.

More you have to set a cookie and session variable to complete your localization and redirection logic, take hint from here https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9347/redirect-user-based-on-country